# Method call not returning from event but will from console

Tags: meteor, meteor-methods

I have a strange issue that I can't figure out. I have a method and a method call in my template event handle. For some reason the method call only works like 1 time out of 5 and it doesn't update DOM. When the call works, `console.log(Session.get('getReportData')+ " from method call");` returns Objects to console but not to the DOM.

When I set the variable manually in console and call:

```
Meteor.call('getReportData',startDate, finishDate, function(err, data) {
                console.log("is the call working at all??");
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                Session.set('getReportData', data);
                console.log(Session.get('getReportData')+ " from method call");
            });
```

I get everything back and DOM is updated also.

Here is the code:

```
Method:

'getReportData': function(startDate, finishDate) {
        /*
        if (mingi check, mis annaks errorit?) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("no-data-found", "No data can be found for selected period");
        } */
        var reportData = ScrapReport.find({dateEntered: { $gte: startDate}, dateEntered: { $lte: finishDate}}).fetch();
        return reportData;
    }
Client:

Template.report.events({
    'click .btn': function(startDate, finishDate) {
        var startDate = $('#startDate').val();
        console.log(startDate + ' StartfromTheButton')
        var finishDate = $('#finishDate').val();
        console.log(finishDate + ' FinishfromTheButton')

        Meteor.call('getReportData',startDate, finishDate, function(err, data) {
            console.log("is the call working at all??");
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            Session.set('getReportData', data);
            console.log(Session.get('getReportData')+ " from method call");
        });
    }
})

Template.reportData.helpers({
    'reportData': function () {
        return Session.get('getReportData');
    }
});
```

What can cause this issues?

1. Call doesn't work every time.
2. When it works, DOM is not updated?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing event in the function call and `event.preventDefault();`